# How to do routing in Angular version 9?

Tags: angular

I have created a routing like below. But when I browse the page it's not working attached the screenshot. Even the not page found also not working

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BookComponent } from './book/book.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NoPageFoundComponent } from './no-page-found/no-page-found.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'books',
    component: BookComponent,
    data: { title: 'Book List' }
  },
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/books',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: NoPageFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})


export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

[image] 
The below is my folder structure.

[image]

Even my node_modules files like bootstrap.css also not loading. If I open it in browser its showing not found

Kindly check this git repo https://github.com/aathirag/angular9_sample

Comment: can you please share your stackblitz instance?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Kindly share stackblitz instance. Your routing looks good to me.

Comment: I added the console error in my question

Comment: @user1187 You need to import the HttpClientModule in app.module.ts. e.g. import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: Please resolve console errors first, import HttpClientModule in app.module.ts and inject HttpClient service in your ApiService.

Comment: You also have an error because you are trying to import a bootstrap css file that does not exist...

Comment: bootstrap css. I have installed and included in angular.json file  "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.css"              
            ],

Comment: @user1187 Try the path without './'(dot and forward slash) i.e. "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" not "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"

Comment: Now there is no other error. But while loading a page not found or other pages the below error is showing in console. default path is working. sdfsd:1 GET http://localhost:3001/sdfsd 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @user1187 Please upvote if you find my comments useful. Also,localhost:3001/sdfsd doesn't match any path in routing config so it fallbacks to your not found path which is '**'.

Comment: but it should load the page not found page. that is not loading. still showing bootstrap missing if i removed the './'. So for now i removed it fully.

Comment: Like I said your routing looks just fine. Can you share a stackblitz instance?

Comment: I pushed the code in this git repo. https://github.com/aathirag/angular9_sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I got the answer. This issue is from node js side. I have to mention the path in app.js file.